# Como puedo desinstalar los archivos de configuracion de un certificado ssl de letsencrypt?

Tags: apache, certificado-ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

No puedo renovar el certificado actual.

El servidor es Apache, el cual no puedo desinstalar, Quiero arrancar prácticamente de cero con el certbot y poder generar un nuevo certificado.

Espero haberme hecho entender.
Agradezco su ayuda

### Intentos

He intentado el comando

```
sudo certbot renew
```

y

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

sin obtener buenos resultados.

He habilitado las configuraciones del firewall para que reciba peticiones HTTPS y no cambia.

He intentado generar un nuevo certificado a través de

```
Certbot = sudo certbot --apache
```

pero no me lo permite con el mismo subdominio que ya tengo registrado.

Comment: Sin obtener buenos resultados se refiere a que no obtuviste ningún mensaje de error?